# how can i remove checkboxes text

Tags: jquery

i can simply remove checked checkboxes with this code

```
  $(".ImdbAddArtist:checked").slideUp('slow');
```

however, i cannot delete checkbox's texts

How can i do that ?

For example

```
   <input type="checkbox" value="1500-374-Tom Cruise" class="ImdbAddArtist" name="artist[]">Tom Cruise
```

for example, when i remove with this code

```
  $(".ImdbAddArtist:checked").slideUp('slow');
```

It only removes checkboxes.How can i remove also text? In example, it's Tom Cruise

Comment: Wrap it with div and remove the whole div

Comment: Every time you build a form, please use [`label` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label) (not just for checkboxes, for every form element). It makes for better user experience and accessibility, and sometimes it also helps the programmer like here ;).

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in a label. The nice thing about wrapping in a label is that the label will be clickable as well.

```
<label id="myLabel"><input type="checkbox" value="1500-374-Tom Cruise" class="ImdbAddArtist" name="artist[]">Tom Cruise</label>
```